# detectLeakedClosableObjects - but what objects?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging

I am trying out strict mode for my android app for the first time. My app reports detectLeakedClosableObjects - but I have no idea how to tell what objects are being referred to. Looking at my logcat I see "onCreate() entry" but not "strict now set". So is the strict mode system simply telling me that there is an unclosed objects somewhere in my entire program? Surely it could be more specific?

```
public void onCreate()
{
  Log.i("myapp", "onCreate() entry" );
  StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
         .detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects()
         .detectLeakedClosableObjects()
         .penaltyLog()
         .penaltyDeath()
         .build());

  Log.i("myapp","strict now set");
  super.onCreate();
```

Comment: This is an old question, so perhaps you've already found your answer.

After you set up StrictMode, it'll spot subsequent leaks, and as you've got penaltyDeath() set it'll throw an exception. It's quite specific about where the leak originated, you should get a stack trace showing you where the Closable object was opened.

If you're not seeing you 'strict now set' logging, that suggests that something's failing in the call to StrictMode.setVmPolicy itself. Have you tried stepping through in the debugger to see what's happening?